# ngFor giving undefined even value is present in array

Tags: javascript, angular

I am traversing through array using ngFor but when i try to access data in value variable.
It is giving value is undefined. why this is happening?

```
myArray = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e'];
  <div *ngFor="let vlaue of myArray">
    <button (click)="divClicked(value)">click {{ value }}</button>
  </div>
```

Comment: Because of typo vlaue

Comment: classic, your typo.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo.

Please change the code below

```
<div *ngFor="let vlaue of myArray">
```

to

```
<div *ngFor="let value of myArray">
```